# How to upload android and iso app containing mysql / php and wrap with phonegap

Tags: javascript, android, json, cordova, phonegap-build

I am trying to make an android and ios app using html, css and passing all mysql with php through JSON so that i can use wrap it up with Phone gap .

All my functions are working when tested on a browser but how can i upload my app and its server side function to a github repository so that i can build using phone gap cloud. I use github repository when i develop apps without mysql.

If i am to upload the mysql to a remove server and the app to github, How do i link it.

below is my php connection to database

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

$user="root";
$pass="xxxx";
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=uxxxmobile', $user, $pass);
?>
```

Here is my login function
'

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#loginForm').on('submit',function(e){

        var myForm = new FormData($(this)[0]);
        var host = 'http://example.com/uixxxmobile/connections';

        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url: host + '/login.php',
            data : new FormData($(this)[0]),
            cache: false,
            contentType:false,
            processData: false,
            beforeSend: function(){
                $("div#divLoading").show();
            },
            success: function(response){
                $("div#divLoading").hide();
                console.log(response);
                if(response.success == true)
                {
                    window.location.href = "profile.html";
                }

                else if( response.success == false ){
                    alert('please enter a correct email & password');
                }
                else if(response.matric =="") {
                        alert('email is wrong');
                    }
                    else if(response.password==""){
                        alert('password is wrong');
                    }

            },
            error: function(data){
                alert('Login fail. Check your login details correctly');
                $("div#divLoading").hide();
            }
        });
    return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

and my profile function

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    var host = 'http://example.com/uixxxmobile/connections';

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: host + '/profile.php',
        data: 'param=no' ,
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success: function (response) {
            console.log(response);
            var input ="";
            input +='<b>' + response.name + '</b><br>';
            input += response.faculty + '<br>';
            input += response.dept + '<br>';
            input +=response.school + '<br>';

            var cumgrade= response.cumgpa;
            var currentgrade= response.currentgpa;
            $('#basicContent').html(input);
            $('#cumgpa').html(cumgrade);
            $('#currentgpa').html(currentgrade);
            $('#level').html(response.level + ' Level ' +response.semester+ ' Semester')



        },
        error: function (e){
            alert (e);
        }

    });

    $('#mycourses').load('connections/user-course.php');

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You link it by ajax call. In my app, I use ajax in jquery:

```
var host = 'your host address - ex: http://example.com/php/';

$.ajax({
    url: host + "/driverlogin.php",
    type: 'POST',
    cache: false,
    data: $('#frmdriverlogin').serialize(),
    success: function(arr) {//handle success}, error: function(){//handle error}   });
```

Comment: Thanks Mr Neo but when i use my login function it does fetch the contents from my database. I just uploaded my code.